# How to display table data in HTML code to php code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to display data like in below image format, the data is in database, it's where I retrieve the data.

I want to know how do i display data like the image below:
[image]

Here is my html form code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>index</title>
        <link href="newhtml.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="submitData.php">
        <table class="Index" action="newhtml2.html">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="createAccount">CREATE ACCOUNT</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="bussiness name" class="textName" required/> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea cols="17" rows="4" name="address" placeholder="bussines address" class="textAddress" required></textarea> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea cols="17" rows="4" name="description" placeholder="post update information" class="postTxtArea" required></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="email address" class="textEmail" required/> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" maxlength=10 name="mobilenumber" placeholder="mobile number" class="textMobile" required/> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="primaryBtn" id="customId"/> 
                </td>
            </tr>![data i want to display like the image link i gave][2]
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what you have done for display data?

Comment: display data in not table format ....like this am sending the image

Comment: image is www.bhavyatechnologies.com/demos/mmw/search-results.html       here box format like that i want to display details please help me anyone please

Answer (score 0):

you will have to first make a database connection using PHP mysqli or PDO.

Then fire your query and store results in a variable and then run a loop while the query contains the value.

```
<?php
mysqli_connect('','','','') //Set your parameters

$query="Your query";

$res=mysqli_query($query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
echo "<table><tr><td>".$row['col_name']."</td></tr></table>";

}
```

Add your db cols as per your table

Comment: ok sir what you are told that is correct but i want to display the data in this format .please see this link  http://www.bhavyatechnologies.com/demos/mmw/search-results.html   here in this link data is display in one box.like that i want to display data .please help sir please any one